# DRY maxima tracking

Tags: java

Suppose I am importing table entries, where a single entry can be stored in a class:

```
class Foo {
  int i1;
  int i2;
  double d1;
}
```

After the import is complete, I will need to have access to the imported values themselves, as well as to their normalized versions. So far, I have implemented this functionality as follows:

```
class FooWithMaxTracking {
  private int i1;
  private static int i1_max=0;
  public void setI1(int value){
    this.i1 = value;
    if (value > i1_max) { i1_max = value; }}
  public int getI1(){
    return i1;}
  public double normI1(){
    return i1/((double)i1_max);}

  private int i2;
  private static int i2_max=0;
  public void setI2(int value){ <code identical to written above> }
  public int getI2(){ ... }
  public double normI2(){ ... }

  // and another set of similar 2 variables & 3 functions for 'double d1'
}
```

In this implementation I strongly dislike the fact that I had to write the same code many times (only three in this example, but about ten times in the real project). Is there any way to make the code more DRY ("don't repeat yourself")?

Comment: Is FooWithMaxTracking operating on the data held in Foo?

Comment: An entry consists of two ints and a double. If I wanted only to store the values, I would use `Foo`. However, since I need to track maximum value for each field, I must use `FooWithMaxTracking` instead of `Foo`. That is, these classes are alternative representations for the same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind a slight loss of performance, you can put all the maxima in a static `Map`, define a class that holds a getter, a setter, and a norm methods, and replace the individual variables with instances of that class:

```
private static Map<String,Object> max = new HashMap<String,Object>();
private static class IntMaxTrack {
     private final String key;
     private int value;
     public IntMaxTrack(String k, int v) {
         key = k;
         value = v;
         max.put(key, value);
     }
     public int get() { return value; }
     public void set(int v) {
         int m = ((Integer)max.get(key)).intValue();
         value = v;
         if (value > m) {
             max.put(key, value);
         }
     }
     public double norm() {
         int m = ((Integer)max.get(key)).intValue();
         return val / ((double)m);
     }
}
```

Make a similar class for `double`, i.e. `DblMaxTrack` Now you can replace primitives with instances of these classes, and call their `get`, `set`, and `norm` from the corresponding methods of your class.

Comment: if those values are hashed correctly the loss of performance is negliable. And the fact that this code is MUCH better than the original compansates that

Comment: This could probably be the answer. To understand, I will have to understand what `HashMap` is and how it works... Anyway, thanks for an idea.

Comment: Why do we need the `.intValue()` call in `norm()` method?

Comment: @skobls We don't need it - autoboxing will take care of it. I added it to be explicit about storing a wrapper instead of a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining one class with the necessary code, like:

```
public class Bar {
    private int i1;
    private static int i1_max = 0;

    public void setI1(int value) {
      // ...
    }

    public int getI1() {
      // ...
    }

    public double normI1() {
      // ...
    }
}
```

And using it sevearl times, like:

```
class FooWithMaxTracking {
    one = new Bar();
    two = new Bar();
    three = new BarForDouble();
}
```

Comment: I tried that. your variables `one` and `two` will have a shared maximum. This is not acceptible.

Comment: So why don't you make it adjustable, e.g. introduce a constructor parameter like `public Bar(int maximum) {...}`

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your point. How would you use a constructor parameter to prevent `i1` and `i2` from accumulating maximum in the same variable?

Comment: Maybe I missed your point... I though you have two int-values and some methods operating on those 2 values. And that repeated several times: i1, i2, ... If that's the case, you could create different instances with distinct maximums by calling `new Bar(5)` for a maximum of 5 or `new Bar(7)` for a maximum of 7.